# How to transfer sql query to django orm code which contains &

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, django-orm

For example, how to translate

```
SELECT id FROM goods WHERE (goods.id & 1) =1
```

to django orm code

Comment: If datatype is some xINT then you may use `WHERE goods.id MOD 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Goods.objects.extra(where=['id & 1 = 1'])
```

or

```
Goods.objects.annotate(flag_fiter=F('id').bitand(1)).filter(flag_fiter=1)
```